# How to dump classes loaded into memory? Java

Tags: java, debugging, jar, jvm, reverse-engineering

I am trying to access a java package loaded into memory and dump it to a file. Here is how the security works: there is an exe packed with Themida that contains the java main class code to be loaded. At runtime the Themida exe loads the clean main class java code into memory. The software is structured with the loader being contained within the exe, but several external libraries can access the packages contained within the exe. So, exe contains com.mysoft.mainloader. But the clean jar library Mylib.jar can call functions within com.mysoft.mainloader. How to I dump com.mysoft.mainloader to a jar file? Can I modify Mylib.jar to dump it as it has access to the package once it is loaded as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get loaded classes in runtime using [Dynamic Attach](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.attach/com/sun/tools/attach/VirtualMachine.html) and [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).

The idea is to inject a Java Agent into the running application.
The agent gets an array of all loaded classes with [`Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses()) method, then gets their bytecode using [`Instrumentation.retransformClasses`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#retransformClasses(java.lang.Class...)).

The working implementation can be found in the [class-file-extractor](https://github.com/apangin/class-file-extractor) project.

Usage:

```
java -jar extractor.jar <pid> mainloader.jar com.mysoft.mainloader
```

where

- `<pid>` is the process ID of the target JVM application;
- `mainloader.jar` is the output file name;
- `com.mysoft.mainloader` is the name prefix of the classes to extract.

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported Java SE mechanism to read / retrieve a ".class" that has been loaded by a classloader.  So your options would be:

- Modify the custom classloader you are using to capture the ".class" before (or after) the classloader calls `defineClass`.
- Burrow into the JVM data structures to try and figure out whether the entire ".class" stream is captured somewhere and then retrieve it.
- Modify the JVM ...

Any of these *could* be feasible.  All *will* be relatively difficult.